# How to add external js file and jq library from cdn in wordpress theme?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewvEF.png)I am calling my external Js file in my WordPress theme but its showing some error and not working

i did the possible way but its not working.

```
function creative_resources() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri(), '', 1.0);
    wp_enqueue_script('script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/main.js', array('jquery'), 1.1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('script-jqlib', get_template_directory_uri().'js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js', array('jquery'), 1.1, true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'creative_resources');
```

I just want a sticky menu in my wp theme that is called from my main.js file. Main.js file is called but some error is showing like, and the jq library is failed to load....

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at main.js?ver=1.1:2

 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify your `main.js` file as:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Your Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

Please see [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

and https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-wordpress-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function-jquery-error/